# Get xhr response and parse it

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Hi I make an xmlHttpRequest like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var params = 'gbook_text=' + encodeURIComponent('sdfsdf');

xhr.open("POST", '/gbook/save/7697256.html', true)
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
}


xhr.send(params);
```

And I need to parse some data from response which is just a webpage
I need to parse It via dom methods like getElementById().
I know that I can write something like:

```
xhr.responseXML.getElementById('author')
```

But it works only if server sets a header

> Content-Type: text/xml

Otherwise  responseXML is null

So what are my options?

P.S: only js without any libraries.
P.P.S: browser requirements: chrome, ff, ie8+

Edited: okay options, which one is better:
1)parse xhr.responsetext as a string
2)redirect to response page and parse it.How to do it, btw?

Comment: What are your browser support requirements?

Comment: @Jon ie 8 +, chrome, ff

Comment: How can I reply to you using @Jon in comments?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... you already replied and I got a reply notification (twice). The @ prefix is responsible for the latter, although in some cases the system is smart enough to notify on its own.

Comment: I mean it, i just thought you didn't get a notification, cause it doesn't highlight your nickname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question, you can only get your response back in text, yet you want to search for it as an HTML document,  you can try creating a div and putting the html response as the innerHTML of the div.

```
var res = document.createElement( 'div' );
res.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
res.querySelector("#ElementID")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `responseType` and/or using the `overrideMimeType` method?

```
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
```